# Use numbers to prove that $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid xy \geq 0\}$ is closed under the rule of multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

The question is:

Determine whether each of the following sets is closed under the indicated rule for multiplication of vectors by scalars.

$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid xy \geq 0\}$; standard rule for multiplication of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by scalars.

I did the problem and found out $(k^2)xy$, however, how would you prove that $k^2xy \geq 0$ using numbers? Let’s say $(1,2)$ and $(-2,-1)$ multiplied, the result is $(-2,-2)$. However, if $k=1$, then $1^2(-2,-2)= (-2,-2)$, thus it isn’t enclosed since $(-2,-2) \neq xy \geq 0$. However, the book says that it is enclosed, which doesn’t make any sense! Could anyone please prove it using numbers? That would be greatly appreciated.

Update: Is anyone going to help or am I doing something wrong? Is the question too hard to answer or something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question is :

Determine whether each of the following sets is closed under the indicated rule for multiplication of vectors by scalars.

{(x,y) ∈ R2 | xy ≥ 0}; standard rule for multiplication of vectors in R2 by scalars.

Comment: However, k^2xy isn't >=0 since if k = 1, then 1^2(-2,-1) = (-2,-1) which isn't greater than 0

Comment: That question is really unclear. What do you mean by closed? It seems to me you are meant to multiply two vectors componentwise but you seem to indicate it is only multiplying by scalars, where it is difficult gather a meaning of closed for the latter case

Comment: You think "thus it it's enclosed", the book also says that "it is enclosed", then why do you think this doesn't make any sense?

Comment: you may as well show us what the book says in DETAIL so that we may decipher what is going on

Comment: I meant to say it isn't enclosed

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll update it with a pic of the answer

Comment: I don't follow. Because $(-2)\cdot (-2) \ge 0$, so $(-2, -2)\in\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid xy\ge 0\}$.

Comment: How about (-2,2)

Comment: @COCO21 That is not an element in $S$.

Comment: I emailed by prof and he gave me a nice detailed answer. The property of being closed under scalar multiplication states that any vector in S, multiplied by any scalar, is a vector in S. So we are indeed assuming from the beginning that (x,y) belongs to S, so (x,y) satisfies the property "xy >= 0".

Answer (score 2):

The statement is saying the following "if you take something from $S$, multiply by a scalar, you will still end up with an element in $S$." Let's see how is this so.

Take any element from $S$, say $u=(x,y)$. Because it is an element in $S$, $xy\geq 0$, simply by definition. Now $ku=(kx,ky)$ simply by definition of scalar multiplication. It is left to see if $ku$ is an element of $S$. How to check so? Well $(kx)(ky)=k^2xy\geq 0$ simply because $xy\geq 0$ and $k^2\geq 0$ for obvious reasons. Hence you are done, you have shown what is required.

You are not supposed to **multiply two vectors** component wise, that is not what the book meant.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I’m gonna answer my own post. The property of being closed under scalar multiplication states that any vector in $S$, multiplied by any scalar, is a vector in $S$. So we are indeed assuming from the beginning that $(x,y)$ belongs to $S$, so $(x,y)$ satisfies the property $xy \geq 0$. This means that $k^2xy$ is indeed $\geq 0$ !